# Android Network Security on API <24

Tags: android, security, ssl-certificate, network-security, android-network-security-config

To communicate with back from my android app I use network-security-config.xml, which looks like

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config>
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/my_ca"/>
            <certificates src="system"/>
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

where is my_ca - certificate (.pem file)

On API < 24 it's not working, how to solve this?

Comment: I understand you want to add a custom CA. How do communicate with the server (e.g. Retrofit, OkHttp, ... ) ?

Comment: @bwt  yes, custom CA. with Retrofit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declarative network security configuration was added in Android 7 (API 24). Before that you have to do it programatically. Unfortunately it is not straightforward, the steps are :

- Put the certificate in a `KeyStore`
- Create a `X509TrustManager`
- Create a `SSLSocketFactory`
- Build an `OkHttpClient`
- Use the client in the `Retrofit` builder

There is [OkHttp recipe](https://square.github.io/okhttp/https/#customizing-trusted-certificates-kt-java) describing this.

It seems that there also is an [OkHttp extension](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-tls) with a much simpler API :

```
val certificate = """-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...                
-----END CERTIFICATE
""".decodeCertificatePem()

val certificates: HandshakeCertificates = HandshakeCertificates.Builder()
    .addTrustedCertificate(certificate)
    .addPlatformTrustedCertificates()
    .build()

val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .sslSocketFactory(certificates.sslSocketFactory(), certificates.trustManager)
    .build()

Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(client)
    ...
    .build()
    .create(MyWebService::class.java)
```

A similar sample [in java](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/CustomTrust.java) building the OkHttp client

Comment: thank you so much! I've tested on API 21 and 23 and it works, but  API 24 doesn't work either with network-security-config or this programmatic way

Comment: This is strange, handling the certificate programatically should work with all versions of Android